# Recursive block gets deallocated too early

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have written a recursive block following [these](http://ddeville.me/2011/10/recursive-blocks-objc/) guidelines:

```
NSMutableArray *groups = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"group1", @"group2", @"group3", @"group4"];

__block CommunicationCompletionHandler completion = [^{
    [groups removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    if ([groups count] > 0) {
        // This will send some information to the network, and calls the completion handler when it receives a response
        [mySocket saveGroup:groups[0] completion:completion];
    }
} copy]; // Removing copy here doesn't work either

[mySocket saveGroup:groups[0] completion:completion];
```

In the `saveGroup:completion:` method, I add the completion handler to an array:

```
self.completionHandlers[SaveGroupCompletionHandlerKey] = [completion copy];
```

And when I receive a response, I call the following method (`key` is in this case `SaveGroupCompletionHandlerKey`):

```
- (void)performCompletionHandlerForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if (self.completionHandlers[key]) {
        ((CommunicationCompletionHandler)self.completionHandlers[key])();
        [self.completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the completion handler only gets called once. The `removeObjectForKey:` line makes the block deallocate. If I uncomment that line, everything works fine. I'm not sure how the array has the last reference to this block, since I add a `copy` (which I believe is being optimized to a `retain`).

For clarity, the flow of the app is:

- Send data for first group over network
- Receive response
- Call completion handler
- In the completion handler, send data for next group (this is the recursive part).

Anybody here who can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `-performCompletionHandlerForKey:` you remove the completion handler from your dictionary *after* executing the block, which means that the handler will always be removed from the dictionary after one run.

Instead, store the block in a temporary variable and remove it from the dictionary before executing the block.

By the way, the advice to remove the weak reference is wrong.  As your code is written now, your block will never be deallocated.  The typical block recursion pattern is this:

```
__weak __block MyBlock weakHandler;
MyBlock handler = ^ { 
    if (foo) {
        MyBlock strongHandler = weakHandler;
        [bar asyncOperationWithCompletion:strongHandler];
    }
};

weakHandler = handler;
[bar asyncOperationWithCompletion:handler];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are correct, that solves the problem. Could you expand a little more on why the strong/weak advice was wrong? Doesn't the block simply go out of scope once (in your example) `foo` equals `NO`?

Comment: @Scott: In non-ARC code, you would -copy the block, and then -release the block once recursion has completed.  ARC takes care of that for you, except it doesn't know when the recursion ends and has no place to insert the -release.  Thus you have a -copy with no -release, and a leak.  (If ARC simply released the block at the end of execution, calling the block twice in a row would cause an over-release).  One way around that is to manually set the block variable to nil once recursion has completed.  That forces ARC to insert -release at the correct location, but that approach is error-prone.

Comment: @Darren: "and then -release the block once recursion has completed." No. You would release the block after its last use in this function, which is after it's passed to `asyncOperationWithCompletion:`

Comment: This is much cleaner than other solutions I've seen where the block is passed to itself as a bridge casted void pointer.

Answer (score -1):

A popular way to avoid retain retain cycles is to create a weak reference to the object before defining the block, then create a strong reference inside the block and set it to that weak reference. This method is frequently used to avoid strongly capturing `self` inside of blocks:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    __weak MyType *weakSelf = self;
    [self someMethodWithABlockArg:^{
        MyType *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf someOtherMethod];
    }];
}
```

The strong reference created inside the block prevents the object from being deallocated while the block is running. You can, of course, do the same with any object type.

Edit2: Looks like `[someBlock copy]` is indeed fine. Have you tried running Analyze on the code? It may be that `completion` is not yet initialized when it is referred to inside of the block.

Comment: The question has been edited, the first version used a weak reference (otherwise my answer would not make any sense :-)

Comment: Thanks, but that document is outdated. It was last modified over 2 years ago, before ARC was even a thing. As far as I know, copying a block is just fine.

Comment: this is not relevant to the question